# Unity C# Json Read/Write

Tags: c#, json, read-write

My **Code** is referencing https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html

Inside of my LoadJson() method is a commented out print statement to show a certain json value I know it would be

```
x["Character0"]["Head"].ToString()
```

to show the head Value, I think my issue is the return type in method

```
 public static SaveCharacters CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
```

*But I am at a loss with Json in C# any help would be nice I haven't found any useful solutions.*

**Json File**

```
{
"Character0":{
    "Head":"HeadCube",
    "Neck":"NeckCube",
    "Body":"BodyCube",
    "Arms":"Sphere_Capsule_Arms",
    "Legs":"Sphere_Capsule_Legs"
    }
}
```

**Code**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

[System.Serializable]
public class SaveCharacters
{
private string json;
private string Head, Neck, Body, Arms, Legs;

private static SaveCharacters _Instance;

public static SaveCharacters Instance { get { return _Instance; } }
void Awake() {
    if (_Instance != null)
    {
        _Instance = this;
    }
}
// Start is called before the first frame update
public void starts()
{
    LoadJson();
}

private void LoadJson()
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Assets/JSON/CustomCharacters.json"))
    {
        json = r.ReadToEnd();
        Debug.Log(json);
        SaveCharacters x =CreateFromJSON(json);

        //Debug.Log(x[""][""]);
    }
}
public void Load(string savedData)
{
    JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(savedData, this);
}
public string SaveToString()
{
    return JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
}
public static SaveCharacters CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
{
    return JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveCharacters>(jsonString);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us Suppose that you have This Json File :

```
{
  "Player": {
    "Score": 1
  },
  "Teams":{
    "Levels": {
      "Level": 1
    }
  }
}
```

and you want to Get the Score Value :

First : download this Library [SimpleJson](https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON)

and then call it like this :

```
JSONNode node = JSON.Parse( jsonString );
string score = node["Player"]["Score"].Value;
```

Comment: Does this allow simple editing of values to json file or adding/deleting objects to json file?

Comment: you can use this asset  [JSON .NET For Unity] (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347) for read and Write and serialize objects.